# How to enable / disable click in spinner android?

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

Based on the condition i would like “to show the drop down view of a spinner or show a default value and do not show the drop down”. I used setClickable(false) in the spinner object but it didn’t work. How to implement it?

Comment: Have you tried to setEnabled(false); ?

Comment: setenabled(false) works, but it greys out the field. I don't want that to go to disabled state.

Comment: You can change the disabled color to look normal by using state selector

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
((Spinner) spinner).getSelectedView().setEnabled(false);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: setenabled(false) works, but it greys out the field. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Disable or enable it before setting the adapter.

```
spinner.setEnabled(false);   
spinner.setClickable(false);  
spinner.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

enable/disable spinner  it at the end of by writting this below line.

spinner.onSelectedItemListener

spinner.setEnabled(false);  // programmatically

Answer (score 0):

To disable click in single item spinner without it greys out the field:

create xml layout for spinner item **spinner_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#000000"         
/>
```

In the code:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_item, SpinnerList); // replace SpinnerList with your own list you want to show
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.android_spinner); // replace android_spinner with the id of yours
        if (SpinnerList.size() < 2) { // again change SpinnerList
            spin.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // if you don't want to show the dropdown arrow
            spin.setEnabled(false); // it will disable click in spinner
        }
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```